# opencv template matching result

Tags: opencv

When using `matchTemplate` from `OpenCV`, how do you programmatically know if the call returned a good result or not?

The function always returns an array image and the location of the top-left or the bottom-right angle of the detected area depending on the method but no information is returned about whether the match is good or not.

Is visual inspection the only way to do this?

Comment: the result Mat holds values which are the matching quality for each pixel. Depending on the input parameters you can either find higher values to be good matches or lower values to be good matches. Tje threshold might depend on your task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template matching is a method that check how much two images are similar to each other.

The process of images comparison is done by correlation methods, in order to understand better you'll have to understand the [equations](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=matchtemplate#matchtemplate)

The most common method (I believe) is Normalize Cross Correlation

```
CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED
```

This method calculate all the correlation coefficients for every displacement between the input images.

After the template matching, you can filter the results by decent threshold, lets say 0.5, to check if the images are similar (this threshold depends on your input images, e.g lightning, different sensor types ect.), than look for the max value displacement.

```
Mat frame, subFrame, result; 
MatchTemplate(frame, subFrame, result, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED); 
double minVal; double maxVal; Point minLoc; Point maxLoc;
Point matchLoc;
minMaxLoc( result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc);
if (maxVal < 0.5)
{
    // No match 
     return;
}
```

This means that if you shift subFrame by minLoc, maxLoc pixels to each direction you'd received the most similar displacement for subFrame to match Frame.